# Session cookie not sending with XHR requests

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, express-session

My react app (from domain react-app.com) is loaded inside a website beautiful-site.com and the requests sending from react app doesn't sending the session cookie associated with it.

The workaround I had was added the below header in server and in react app XHR requests sent with `withCredentials: true`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://beautiful-site.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

The issue is I can specify a particular site in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, because the react app will be added to many sites not one.

Is there any way to get the session cookie send from react app?

Comment: For the origin problem, you can look at cors (npm package) configuration. It allow you to determine dynamicaly which domain can be whitelisted...

Comment: potentially related: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](/q/43871637/11107541)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is no, but you have workaround: when you set the withCredentials you can't have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

The fix must be done server side: your API service must returns domain of the request in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, commonly taken from the `Origin` header.

See [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe) (the **How to fix “Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must not be the wildcard” problems** subsection) for techincal details.